# Por que se puede crear un objecto ActionListener?

Tags: java

Por que se puede hacer esto?:

```
JButton.addActionListener(new ActionListener(){//codigo...});
```

No se supone que es una interfaz?

Comment: Esto no es el duplicado que ahí indica. 

Pero para aclarar la pregunta debería ser: 

"¿Por qué se permite crear objetos a partir de interfaces?"

Lo de ActionListener confunde.

No es nada parecido al "propósito de clases anónimas"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Java tiene un mecanismo para hacer "classes anónimas".

Puedes hacer una subclase de otra clase sin darle nombre así:

```
MiClase anonima = new MiClase() {
    @Override
    public void metodo() {
        // una nueva implementación del método
    }
};
```

De la misma manera Java permite crear nuevas **clases** anónimas que **implementan** una interfaz así:

```
MiInterfaz anonima = new MiInterfaz() {
    @Override
    public void metodo() {
        // una nueva implementación del método
    }
};
```

Finalmente, hoy en día si tu interfaz tiene 1 solo método puedes escribirlo de manera más concisa así:

```
MiInterfaz anonima = () -> {
        // una nueva implementación del método
    };
```

Comment: es como una clase interna

Comment: las clases internas se guardan como:

MiClase$Interna.class

Las anonimas como:

MiClase$1.class

Es decir, si.. es como una clase interna, pero no tiene nombre.

Answer (score 0):

JButton es un clase.  Tiene que tener un objecto en concreto para llamar ese metodo, como así

```
JButton Digame = new JButton();
Digame.AddActionListener(...);
```